# Youtube data becomes inaccessible against restricted google API key

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

Though this question is asked several times, but my concern is why there is an error of mismatch of package name and fingerprint when things are absolutely identical (copy-pasted).

Data(videos and stats) For a non-restricted google API key against youtube-v3-api is being fetched properly but as I restrict the key on google console (passing package name and fingerprint in the header of API request) data becomes unavailable. following is the api response statement

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
        "message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, 
 "Package_name" and 
 "Finger_Print", do not match the app restrictions 
 configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
        "extendedHelp": "Project_Link_Google_Console"
      }
   ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, 
 "Package_name" and 
 "Finger_Print", do not match the app restrictions 
 configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
 }
}
```

It says "package name and fingerprint do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key" though these are copy-pasted from code to console.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got rid of this issue by passing the sha1 key in the request header call without colons ":"
e.g replacing the following line

```
"80:F1:B6:4I:2A:Z6:B7:51:9C:BA:21:FC:0C:C8:2F:C5:4Z:20:ZA:X1"
```

with

```
"80F1B64I2AZ6B7519CBA21FC0CC82FC54Z20ZAX1"
```

Previously I was passing the sha1 key in the header as it was mentioned on google developer console.